# Nginx configuration for SSL - React - Node - Cloudflare

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, nginx, cloudflare

I'm really noob with Nginx and i dont know how to configure `nginx` properly, my project folder its

```
/Client (react)
/Server (node)
/ (server config)
```

i had this `nginx` config before and everything works perfect

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name IP;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://IP:3030;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

later on `Cloudflare` I active *only https*, my website cant connect to the backend on port :4000, with some research i found that i need to change `nginx` config, this is what `Cloudflare` guides me to create.

```
server {
  listen     80;
  listen     443;

  ssl        on;
  ssl_certificate         /root/certificate.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key     /root/key.key;

  server_name    mydomain.org www.mydomain.org;
  access_log     /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
  error_log      /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
  location / {   # i just paste everything i had on the previous config here
    proxy_pass https://IP:3030;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

So basically, the website loads but it cant handle request to the back-end.

in case you dont know why i have `/server` folder and `/` folder, here's my `server.js` file:

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 3030;
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("/*.png", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params[0]);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/public/", req.params[0] + ".png"));
});
app.get("/*.jpeg", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.params[0]);
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/public/", req.params[0] + ".jpeg"));
});

app.get("/*", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build/", "index.html"));
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Sorry for long post, but i don't know anything for `nginx`, i want to cover almost everything i have.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your backend server is not prepared to handle SSL requests. You can have your NGINX handling that for you and communicating with your backend WITHOUT SSL, which worked before. You can achieve that by changing you `proxy_pass` directive back to a `http://` address.

```
server {
  # Other stuff ...
  location / {
     # Comunicate proxy with backend without encryption until you setup SSL on your application...
     proxy_pass http://IP:3030;
     # Other stuff...
  }
}
```